# how to get percentages on a bar chart (Google Data Studio)

Tags: looker-studio, calculated-field

The problem
How can I get qty percentages to show on a bar chart, with a couple of items filtered and on with dates on axsis x?

The data model:

| Date | Item | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2021 | item1 | 50 |
| 02/02/2021 | item1 | 20 |
| 02/03/2021 | item2 | 80 |
| 02/02/2021 | item3 | 100 |

Isuppose I'd have to do a sum case for the items and then divide it by a calculated field Sum(Qty), but how would I do that if the items may be filtered by the user?

EDIT:
I've tried applying the built-in calculation, but it gives me the wrong result:
[image]

It spreads the percentages horizontally, but I need it to be a vertical analysis.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I didn't find out how to do it in vertical bars, but the 100% Stacking bars will give you the correct result (The percentage of each category in each date) and more or less the same visual information. Just add the date as the dimension and the item as the drill down dimension.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

May be try to check the 'stacked bar' option on Style. [image]

Answer (score -1):

Simply select **Percent of total** under **Comparison calculation** when making the bar chart.

Like this:

[image: screenshot of Comparison calculation]

Comment: Hi! I had tried it and it gives me the wrong result, as explained in the update I've added above.

Comment: As the OP said, that still provides % horizontally for all days. We want it vertically for that specific day. For example, March 3 should have something around 90% and bar 2 would be 10%. These are just examples stats instead of 8% and 2%